# Kafka Connect - From JSON records to Avro files in HDFS

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

My current setup contains Kafka, HDFS, Kafka Connect, and a Schema Registry all in networked docker containers.

The Kafka topic contains simple JSON data without a Schema:

```
{
    "repo_name": "ironbee/ironbee"
}
```

The Schema Registry contains a JSON Schema describing the data in the Kafka Topic:

```
{"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
"$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
"type": "object",
"title": "Root Schema",
"required": [
    "repo_name"
],
"properties": {
    "repo_name": {
        "type": "string",
        "default": "",
        "title": "The repo_name Schema",
        "examples": [
            "ironbee/ironbee"
        ]
    }
}}
```

What I am trying to achieve is a Connection that reads JSON data from a Topic and dumps it into files in HDFS (Avro or Parquet).

```
{
"name": "kafka to hdfs",
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs3.Hdfs3SinkConnector",
"topics": "repo",
"hdfs.url": "hdfs://namenode:9000",
"flush.size": 3,
"confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafka-1:19092,kafka-2:29092,kafka-3:39092",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081"
}
```

If I try to read the raw JSON value via the StringConverter (no schema used) and dump it into Avro files it works, resulting in

```
Key=null   Value={my json} touples
```

so no usable structure at all.

When I try to use my schema via the JsonSchemaConverter I get the errors

```
“Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic”
“Unknown magic byte”
```

I think that there is something wrong with the configuration of my connection, but after a week of trying everything my google-skills have reached their limits.

All the code is available here: https://github.com/SDU-minions/7-Scalable-Systems-Project/tree/dev/Kafka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> raw JSON value via the StringConverter (no schema used)

schemas.enable property **only** exists on JSONConverter. Strings don't have schemas. JSONSchema always has a schema, so property also doesn't exist there.

> When I try to use my schema via the JsonSchemaConverter I get the errors

Your producer needs to use Confluent JSONSchema Serializer. Otherwise, it doesn't get sent to Kafka with the "magic byte" referred to in your error.

I personally haven't tried converting JSON schema records to Avro directly in Connect. Usually the pattern is to either produce Avro directly, or convert within ksqlDB, for example to a new Avro topic, which is then consumed by Connect.